# Reverse the order of words in python using stack

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, stack, reverse

I am trying to use stack to reverse the order like if j="this is sentence" so the output will be "sentence is this" to do this I try to put it in stack and then pop them out like

```
stack.push(j.split(' '))
```

and then pop it as

```
while not stack.is_empty()
  print stack.data.pop(),
```

but what stack.push(j.split(' ')) does it puts the whole sentence as single entity in the stack like

> [['this','is','a','sentence']]

and hence when i pop it it gives result

> ['this','is','a','sentence']

means nothing reversed at all in nutshell.so how should i split and push the word in stack so that i can reverse the order of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack.push` places the given element/argument on t**op of stack**. For you case the element/argument is whole list. You need to push each element of list seperately. So, replace:

```
stack.push(j.split(' '))
```

by:

```
for i in j.split():
    stack.push(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all stack.push(j.split(' ')) doesnt return splited words. It returns an object with splited words. So that when you push j.split(' ') in a stack, it actually push all words as an object. In the end when you poped up it returns the last entry and that is the object ['this','is','a','sentence'].

```
class Stack():

  def __init__(self):
    self.items = []

  def isEmpty(self):
    return self.items == []

  def push(self, item):
    return self.items.append(item)

  def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()

  def getElements(self):
    return self.items

  def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

  def size(self):
    return len(self.items)

j="this is sentence"
stack = Stack()
jj = j.split(' ')
for word in jj:
    stack.push(word)
print stack.getElements()
print stack.peek() # shows you latest (last) value of array
print stack.pop()
```

In the code you'll find the object is traversed and pushed each word into stack. Then just simply pop each word.

Comment: Thanx this solution is also helpful

Answer (score 0):

`stack.push(*j.split(' '))`

Python does not consider the list returned by split as a list of arguments unless you explicitly specify that using an asterisk. Otherwise it will simply push a list on the stack

Comment: It did not work it gave a Type Error: push() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Hmm you're right. My bad. In that case you'll need to iterate through and push it one by one as the guy above said.